# Poor local loopback performance on Windows server 2019

Tags: loopback, throughput, windows-server-2019

In 2017 we developed 2 applications that exchanged data over a TCP/IP sockets using the local loopback adapter (127.0.0.1). At that time we were running this on a Dell R740 with windows server 2016 SE and we were able to get a throughput of 1.6 Gbit/s. Now in 2020 we are running the same applications on the a new Dell R740 with exactly the same specs but now running Windows server 2019 SE and we are not able to meet requirement. During the test procedure we are only getting 1.2 - 1.3 GBit/s instead of the required 1.5 GBit/s.

One application is compiled with MinGW and uses Boost 1.66, the other is an Embarcadero project and these haven't changed since 2017. Both applications enable the "fast path loopback". The installation (users, other applications, rolls, etc...) of the Dell server is the same.

Can somebody explain why the local loopback throughput has dropped this much since Windows Server 2016 SE?

We also observed that when the run the applications both applications as administrator, the throughput goes up, what can explain this?

The same test is repeated using 2 10G adapters that this resulting in a better performance than using the local loopback adapter..